# Post form data to a new page and show that page with the posted data

Tags: php, jquery

I have: 
form.php
preview.php

form.php has a form in it with many dynamically created form objects. I use jquery.validation plugin to validate the form before submitting. 
submit handler:

```
submitHandler: function() {
             var formData = $("#myForm").serialize();
            $.post("preview.php", {data: formData },function() {
    window.location.href = 'preview.php';
});
```

Question: 
- How to change the current page to preview.php and show the data? my submitHandler doesnt work? Any tips?

preview.php:

```
$results = $_POST['data'];
        $perfs = explode("&", $results);
        foreach($perfs as $perf) {
            $perf_key_values = explode("=", $perf);
           $key = urldecode($perf_key_values[0]);
           $values = urldecode($perf_key_values[1]);
        }
        echo $key, $values;
    enter code here
```

Comment: If possible with your app,try returning the perview page bound to the submitted data and modify the script to : $.post("preview.php", {data: formData },function(data) { 
    $("#divPreview").attr("innerHTML",data); });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem. without sessions.

add to form:

```
 <form action="preview.php" onsubmit="return submitForPreview()">
 <input type="hidden" name="serial" id="serial" value="test">
```

js:

```
function submitForPreview()
{
    if($("#form").valid()){
        $('#serial').val($("#newAdForm").serialize());
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

preview.php

```
echo $_POST['serial']; 
//Which shows the serialized string. YEEEEYYY :D
```

Thanks for help folk :D

Answer (score 0):

Just submit the form without ajax and make sure `action` of form is "preview.php"

EDIT: to do this in validation plugin simply remove the submitHandler option you show above. This is used if you want to over ride normal browser form submit, which you now don't want to do.

WIth your ajax submit, then trying to go to the page.... it is 2 page requests and without the form redirecting automatically there is no data available on page load using the javascript redirect

Comment: I need ajax to validate and serialize the form.

Comment: then you would need to store all the data in a session

Comment: validation can be done without ajax as I added in my comments in answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the onsubmit even of the form and use your validation check along a function. At the end if anything is going good, return it with a true state otherwise, false to stop it from getting submitted.

For example:

```
<form name="Iran" method="POST" action="preview.php" onsubmit="return alex90()">
</form>
```

And use this script:

```
<script language="javascript">
function alex90()
{
// use whatever validation you want
if(form == valid){
return true;
}else{
alert("Something's wrong folk!");
return false;
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: jquery.validator plugin has a method called valid() which returns a bool if the selected form is valid. The problem is that I cant send the $("#aForm").serialize(); to preview.php.   function alex90()
{
 if($("#aForm").valid()){
  var formData = $("#newAdForm").serialize();
  // HOW DO I SEND formData???
  return true;
 }else{
  alert("Something's wrong folk!");
  return false;
 }
}